If I use ephemeral keys to encrypt files, can the master key prove that I'm the owner of the files after the ephemeral keys have been deleted?
I am considering a scenario where I use ephemeral (temporary) encryption keys to encrypt my files. These ephemeral keys are generated specifically for encrypting the files and are not intended to be stored long-term. Once the encryption process is complete, these ephemeral keys are deleted. However, I have a master key that I used to generate these ephemeral keys in the first place.
Given this setup, I want to understand the following:
Can the master key, which is still in my possession, be used in any way to demonstrate or prove that I am indeed the original owner of these encrypted files?
After the ephemeral keys are deleted, what cryptographic methods or processes (if any) could be used to trace back to the master key, thereby linking the encrypted files to me?
Is there a way to securely establish ownership or authentication of the files post deletion of the ephemeral keys?
In essence, I'm trying to determine if there is a method to prove ownership of files encrypted with ephemeral keys using the master key once the ephemeral keys are no longer available

Are these encrypted files intended to be decrypted at some point?  If so, how do you intend to do so, given that you deleted the ephemeral encryption keys?  This goes to your question - if you do have a way (presumably using your master key), that may be key (pun intended) in proving your ownership...
